# How can $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}} = 1+\sqrt{3}$?

Tags: radicals

I'm a high school student and I'm currently studying a lot of Numerical Sets and Radicals then I came across with a problem that wants me to explain why $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}} = 1+\sqrt{3}$, but I don't know how to do, this was my equation: $\sqrt{4} + \sqrt{2}\times\sqrt[4]{3}$ = $2 + \sqrt[4]{2^2\times3}$ = $2 + \sqrt[4]{2^2\times2+1}$ = $2 + \sqrt[4]{2^3 + 1}$. Where is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers. Proper formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @projectilemotion I'm improving the question a little more to make it clearer, just a second. Thanks for the reply by the way.

Comment: In general $\sqrt {a+b}\;\ne \sqrt a\;+\sqrt b.$ ... E.g. $2=1+1=\sqrt 1 \;+\sqrt 1\ne \sqrt {1+1}.$  We have $\sqrt {4+2\sqrt 3}\; \ne \sqrt 4+\sqrt {2\sqrt 3}.$

Comment: Why shouldn't? They are both positive and they have the same square, hence they are equal.

Answer (score 2):

To eliminate a square root, you need a square.

In
$$\sqrt{4+2\sqrt3},$$ $3$ is obviously not a square and we can't simplify it. But is $4+2\sqrt3$ a square ?

Here we need to make the educated guess that this expression could be the square of  $$a+b\sqrt3,$$ i.e.

$$a^2+2\sqrt3ab+3b^2.$$

This is a good candidate as we get an integer term and another which is a multiple of $\sqrt3$.

By inspection, we immediately see that $a=b=1$ works, hence

$$\sqrt{4+2\sqrt3}=1+\sqrt3.$$

Comment: I know it may sounds obvious for you but, for me it doesn't could you explain it in more details? Or put some references that will help me understand it?

Comment: @iszwnc: I already added more details than I could.

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is incorrect:
$$\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}\neq \sqrt{4}+\sqrt{2}\times \sqrt[4]{3}$$
In general:
$$\sqrt{a+b}\neq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$$
Where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

For example, $a=4, b=9$ does not satisfy.

---

**Here is a hint for a correct approach:**

Notice that one may write:
$$4+2\sqrt{3}=1+2\sqrt{3}+3=1^2+2\sqrt{3}+(\sqrt{3})^2$$
Now use the fact that: $$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$

Comment: But why did you cut the square in $\sqrt{4+2}$ and started directly from $4+2$? And if $\sqrt{a + b}\neq\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$, you're saying that it's absurd to sum roots?

Comment: projectilemotion merely squared both sides of the original equation. In fact once you square both sides you can see the two sides are equal $4+2\sqrt{3}=1+2\sqrt{3}+3 \Rightarrow 4+2\sqrt{3} = 4+2\sqrt{3}$ by adding the one and three on the RHS.